# How to cross-reference labels in the text using LyX?

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I'm having trouble using labels and cross-referencing in Lyx.  I put a label into the document where I want it.  It is not embedded in anything, it's just in the text.  Then I put a cross-reference to link it at a different point in the paper.  When I make the pdf, the cross-reference does not go to the link but rather to the top of the section it's in.  What going on?  However, within Lyx, whenever I use the (Navigate Bar -> Other Lists -> Labels and References) then the reference appears to work fine.  It's just not working in the pdf..

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You must be loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) also. What does the cross-reference print in the document? A number of the section or just text? If you want it to just to the correct location, you'll have to place an ERT with `\phantomsection` *just* before the label.

Comment: In the document the number of the section is printed.  The \phantomsection works. Thank you.

Comment: Is that what you want? If so, then all you need to do is insert an ERT with `\phantomsection` just *before* the label. Then your reference will jump to that spot in the PDF.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that a `\label` attaches itself to the last numbered element in the document -- in your case a section -- it does not correspond to the exact position in the code/PDF.

As an alternative to Werner's suggestion, is to use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` from `hyperref`. There is as far as I know no way of accessing these via the LyX GUI however, so you have to add them in ERTs. And as `hyperref` is required, you have to enable that under Document --> Settings --> PDF Properties, if you haven't already.

The syntax for these commands is

```
\hyperlink{<name>}{<text>}
\hypertarget{<name>}{<text>}
```

where `<name>` is the `label`, and `<text>` is printed in the PDF. As there is no support for these in the GUI, you can't use LyX' cross-referencing mechanism.

An example is seen in the screenshot below. I added `\hypertarget{thing}{Cool stuff!}` one place, and `\hyperlink{thing}{Check this out.}` where I wanted the link to be. Note that `<text>` in the `\hypertarget` can be empty if you want that.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that there is currently no LyX GUI way of doing this. I would like to implement it as many users find it useful, especially for Beamer presentations.