# Referencing a labeled piece of text

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am trying to refer to a line of text in my document using \label and \ref options in latex, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\bigskip
\mhead{Publications}
{Paper published in xyz journal, 2016. \label{myposter}}

%...
%after two pages
%...

\begin{itemize}
\item[•]See poster~\ref{myposter}.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You could consider putting the publication in a bibliography and then `\cite` it in the itemize (and print it wherever you like using `\bibliography` or similar).

Comment: Alright, after some searching I was able to find best answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140377/how-to-cross-reference-labels-in-the-text-using-lyx?rq=1